# Displaying and selecting data from a database in a module

Tags: 7, database

I have a database table (gpx_api) with the following fields:

```
runID   userID  score   distance    pace    speed   gpx_path    missionID   startTime   duration
```

I want to display all of these fields from within a module.

I have searched a lot on stack and I got until here:

```
   $query = db_select('gpx_api', 'run')
     ->fields('run')
     ->condition('runID', $firstparameter, '=')
     ->execute()
     ->fetchAssoc();
```

Do I only select the row where runID = $firstparameter like this?

This should only return one result. Now how can I display the fields one by one?

```
$query->distance
```

will not work.

I also tried

```
foreach($query as $result2){
 $result .="DISTANCE";
$result .= $result2->distance;
  }
```

This strangely enough gave a lot of results and errors.

I am sure there is a very simple way, but I am not familiar with the drupal API.

--Update

a var_dump of query gives me:

```
array(10) { ["runID"]=> string(1) "2" ["userID"]=> string(1) "1" ["score"]=> string(2) "10" ["distance"]=> string(3) "200" ["pace"]=> string(1) "7" ["speed"]=> string(1) "8" ["gpx_path"]=> string(0) "" ["missionID"]=> NULL ["startTime"]=> NULL ["duration"]=> NULL }
```

so it is just about displaying the array. Shouldn't $query->distance  work then? Yet if I try it, I get this error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in epicrun_mymenu_page_callback() (line 62 of /home/suneesto/public_html/addons/epicrunapp.com/sites/all/modules/epicrun/epicrun.module).
```

Comment: please read about Result Sets (and working with them): https://drupal.org/node/1251174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic php error, it's $query['distance']